# Django Azure sql server error The session limit for the database is 1200 and has been reached

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, azure-sql-database

I'm developing a django api using Azure sql database, after making request for 1200 times its throwing the error "The session limit for the database is 1200 and has been reached" This is because Azure can have only 1200 concurrent sessions at a time, so after reaching this limit if i restart my server it will drop all the concurrent sessions and it will start again from 0.

Here in database im not using any sessions and authentication, its just a plain django application,
I even tried conn_max_age parameter in settings file with None 0 and 200 500 values also,

I found out that each time i'm making a request azure sql is creating a new entry in storage procedures,
I can see the row created with the command '''EXEC sp_who'''

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Azure SQL database resource limits.
Your SQL database price tier is 'Standard/S2', the max sessions is 1200.
[image]

For more details ,please see [Resource limits for single databases using the DTU-based purchasing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-single-databases).

To improve the Max concurrent works(requests), you need to [scale up the service tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-scale).

Hope this helps.